# How to make python discord bot execute/use a command

Tags: python, discord.py

This is what I have right now and it does successfully sends the message every 60 seconds.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def mytask():
    channel = bot.get_channel(305347032569348107)
    await channel.send('Example message')
```

However when I change `await channel.send('Example message')` to `await channel.send('!coin')` it just sends the !coin message instead of executing/using the !coin command.

and I also tried this `await channel.send(!coin)` but this doesn't even run and shows `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, keep in mind that your bot is only responsible for sending `!coin` to whichever channel. It is up to the bot that actually handles the `!coin` command to decide if it wants to run whatever logic is associated with the `!coin` command and respond or not.
Most discord bots will not even consider "commands" from another bot, to prevent abuse and bot-loops (Discord.js's quickstart guide prevent's bots from executing commands as shown [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#basic-arguments)). So, your best bet is probably to implement the `!coin` command yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the bot send a fake `!coin` message and then execute the script contained in the `coin` command using another built-in command. Here is how you could adjust your current code for `mytask`:

```
@client.command()
async def coin(ctx):
    ...  # Add coin code here

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def mytask(ctx):
    # Send a fake "!coin" message
    channel = bot.get_channel(305347032569348107)
    await channel.send('!coin')

    # Execute the coin command
    await channel.invoke(client.get_command('coin'))
```

Comment: Getting this error `AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'invoke'`